# Disable desktop composition for an application

Tags: registry, compatibility, nsis, dwm

How do I flag an app in Windows Vista/Seven to disable desktop composition thru registry or NSIS script?

Normally it´s done in Compatibility settings in app´s properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must, you can add an entry in the registry in  "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" with the [WriteRegStr](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2) instruction (I don't think there is an official API for this since the user is supposed to control those options, not the developer (After all, you can just fix your broken app) There is a undocumented function called [SHGetAppCompatFlags](http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=studies/windows/shell/shlwapi/api/util/getappcompatflags.htm) to read the flags, but no "setter" AFAIK
)

Answer (score 0):

When your application starts turn off composition using [`DwmEnableComposition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
```

This will disable composition until the (your) offending process exits.

**Note:** This API doesn't modify the user's preference for composition - only that your application is incompatible.

Comment: This no longer achieves anything